What means chirality in 3D space?
I'm self studying orientation in finite-dimensional vector spaces and I was able to undestand the definition and the theory, but I don't quite understand the intuition behind the concept, since orientation is just the generalization of orientation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, I'm focusing on them. According to Wikipedia, orientability in two dimensions allow us to say when a rotation is positive (clockwise) or negative (counterclokwise), this is easy to understand, if $\{u_1, u_2\}$ is and ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we make a rotation in the plane, we just have to check if the orientation goes from $u_1$ to $u_2$ (a positive rotation) or from $u_2$ to $u_1$ (a negative rotation). The problem is when we pass to $\mathbb{R}^3$, the same article mentions

In three dimensions, orientability, allows one to say when a figure is left-handed or right handed.

What does this mean? If we have an oriented basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which now is our model of "right-handed" and if we have a chiral figure in the space, how the basis allow us to say which one is "right-handed" between the original figure an its reflection. Am I missing something?

Read about the right hand rule in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

There is no standard definition of what it means for an arbitrary figure (= subset) in n-space to be "right-handed" or "left-handed" ... and there can be no such definition. The article probably just used a poor choice of words.

Even in two dimensions, how do you really define orientation? You can draw any figure you want in a plane, but its mirror image will have exactly the same measurements; there is just this mysterious "clockwise" and "counterclockwise" thing, which we can see because we are three-dimensional creatures looking at the plane from above.

I should add: Orientability allows one to define two classes of most imaginable shapes (which cannot be translated to become each other), like a right-handed and left-handed spring. (However they are defined, you just know they are mirror images.)  So: Given an orientable manifold as a metric space, most figures will have two forms (and which one you call right-handed and which you call left-handed is a matter of taste, except perhaps for a special menagerie of highly symmetric shapes like the helix.

There is a subtlety in the wording, that they might have gotten wrong. Having an orientation lets us distinguish between two different orientations, but doesn't say which one is right handed and which one is left handed - there is one last (arbitrary) choice to be made.
Maybe think of it like a coin: when you're flipping it it can have any of a whole infinity of orientations. But once it lands there are only 2 possibilities, but which you call 'heads' and which you call 'tails' is still a "1 of 2" choice that you can make either way.
